# convert Hex to Decimal from signed 2's complement in java (0xF8 into -8)

Tags: java, hex, decimal, converters

I have tried to convert **248** to binary and then convert it to two's compliment and finally convert it back to decimal.

Problem: result is **`8`** not **`-8`**

[image]

Comment: don't put code as image

Comment: i have just kept an image of calculation of what i am requiring , its not code

Answer (score 1):

Convert the hex number digit by digit to a 4-bit binary, for example (A) to (1010) and put then together. Now you can calculate the 2‘s complement as explained below. 
You'll see you need at least 9 bits for (F8)<sub>16</sub>, so if you're only working with a 8-bit variable for instance, you might encounter issues.

**Calculating the 2‘s complement:**

1. (248)<sub>10</sub> = (0 1111 1000)<sub>2</sub>.
2. Complement all the bits:
   (1 0000 0111)<sub>2</sub>.
3. Add 1:
   (1 0000 1000)<sub>2</sub>.
   This will give you (-248)<sub>10</sub>. Notice that if you're only looking at the last 8 bits (0000 1000)<sub>2</sub>, the bit string evaluates to 8. I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: can you pls tell me then how the website (in the image i have attach ) is doing calculation

Comment: I don't know how it's implemented on the website. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i have an sensor data which send me data in hex (ex : - f8) and now i want to convert it into Decimal from signed 2's complement (-8)

Comment: Okay, and do you want to do that by hand or write a Java application for the conversion?

Comment: i need to write a code for it

Comment: Okay, and what do you need the 2's complement for?

Comment: i need decimal of 2's complement form hex value

Comment: If I understand correctly, your input is a hex-value, and you need this number to be converted to decimal and binary format?

Comment: decimal from 2's complement binary format

Comment: I updated the answer, see above.

Comment: That being said, the whole 2‘s complement thing depends on the “container” the binary number is supposed to sit in.

Answer (score 0):

Java specifically keeps a single byte in the min/max range of `-128 to 127`. 
A value like **248** (hex: `0xF8`) is already **stored as a Short** (2 bytes or 16 bits) in Java.

`[0000 0000] [1111 1000]` = **248** in Java. But you need only `[1111 1000]` for **-8**.

You'd think *"If I remove starting byte `[0000 0000]` then it works..??"* No because now you have 1 byte left and that remaining byte with `[1111 1000]` alone cannot make **248** since Java's maximum for a single byte is **127**.

**Solution**:
In those available 16 bits, replace all bits leading up to your value with `1`.

Visually your bits `[0000 0000] [1111 1000]`  = **248** must become as `[1111 1111] [1111 1000]` = **-8**.

One quick way to achieve the result is through this logic `result = (-256) | ( x );`.

*Code example:*

```
int x = 248; //# your input value from reading

int result = (-256) | ( x );

System.out.println("value is " + result ); //# gives: value is -8
```